# How to disable pdf view(PDFKIT) internal scrolling?

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, pdf, pdfkit

in my mac application pdfkit using for pdf reader.while scroll the mouse scroll the pages changing how can avoid that.pdfview's display mode is kPDFDisplaySinglePage.No need to work scroll Please help me

Comment: Did you use the setScrollEnabled key setting the scroller

Comment: there is no function for PDFView

Answer (score 9):

Hacky, brittle and a year or two too late, but... the first subview of your PDFView is a private NS/UIScrollView-derived PDFScrollView. Simply cast this and change its `isScrollEnabled` property to `false`, e.g. for iOS:

```swift
(yourPdfView.subviews[0] as! UIScrollView).isScrollEnabled = false
```

Alternatively, and probably a better answer: turn off user interaction for the view, or otherwise intercept and handle it.

Answer (score 1):

**Important notes:**

Make sure you set `displayMode` to `.singlePage` and you are not using `pdfView.usePageViewController(true)`

```
pdfView.displayMode = .singlePage
(pdfView.subviews.first(where: { $0 is UIScrollView }) as? UIScrollView)?.isScrollEnabled = false
```

Answer (score 1):

If displayMode == **.singlePage**, then you can use this method:

```
// MARK: - Disable Scroll
extension PDFView {
    func disableScroll(_ isDisable: Bool) {
        if let scrollView = (self.subviews.first?.subviews.first as? UIScrollView) {
            scrollView.isScrollEnabled = !isDisable
        }
    }
}
```

Call like this:

```
yourPdfView.disableScroll(true)
```